# Enabling Button in Messagebox with timer

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I have a message box that pops up when a user click a button. when user click yes  it's run an `insert` function.

what i want is to add or start a count down when a `messagebox` pop up, the default `yes button` was disabled. and after `5 second` the `yes button`, become `enable` and ready to click by user.

[image: messagebox]

```
  if (MessageBox.Show("log", "test", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {                  
                insert();
            }
```

Comment: You could create your own `MessageBox` class.

Comment: i had never create my own class @@

Comment: @chopperfield don't worry, add form to project and start playing around with properties in designer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, you need to have your own implementation for this functionality. Below is partial code that you will need to modify normal form to make it appear like dialogue box:

1. Add new `Form` to your project. Open the porperties tab. Set properties as give below in point **2**.
2. Modify form in designer to change following properties to given values:

   ```
   this.AcceptButton = this.btnYes;//To simulate clicking *ENTER* (Yes)
   this.CancelButton = this.button2; //to close form on *ESCAPE* button
   this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
   this.MaximizeBox = false;
   this.MinimizeBox = false;
   //FROM CODEPROJECT ARTICLE LINK
   this.ShowInTaskBar = false;
   this.StartPosition = CenterScreen;
   ```
3. Add a timer to form. Set its interval to 5000 (5 seconds). Write code to start timer on `Shown` event of form:

   ```
   private void DialogBox_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       timer1.Start();
   }
   ```
4. Handle ticking of Timer:

   ```
   public DialogBox()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       //bind Handler to tick event. You can double click in 
       //properrties>events tab in designer
       timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;
   }

   private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       btnYes.Enabled = true;
       timer1.Stop();
   }
   ```
5. Set *Yes* button handler:

   ```
   private void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
   }
   ```
6. From where you are showing this custom message box, you can check if `Yes` or `No` is clicked as follows:

   ```
   var d=new DialogBox();
   var result=d.ShowDialog();

   if(result==DialogResult.Yes)
   //here you go....
   ```

Comment: i would see no reason why this should not be accepted as the answer. well explained.

Comment: @TheQuestioner well, i havent test it.. iam trying this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17253/A-Custom-Message-Box and tweak a bit

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot man that was simple. you have my upvote and accepted as answer. in the link i give i still need to know whats `static` for

Comment: @chopperfield “static” means “relating to the type itself, rather than an instance of the type”. You access a static member using the type name instead of a reference or a value, e.g. Guid.NewGuid();

read more here: http:/theburningmonk.com/2010/07/static-vs-non-static-method-in-csharp/